# Is there a polynomial $p$ such that it is bijective and $ p: \mathbb{Q}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ for $ n>1$ ??

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, inverse, applications

Let us define a polynomial $p$   defined as follow $$p: \mathbb{Q}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}.$$

I acrossed this question in mind. Is there a polynomial $p$ such that it is bijective and  $p: \mathbb{Q}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ for $n>1$   ?

**Note**: $p$  is polynomial with $n$  variables $p(x_1,\dots x_n)$.

Thank you for any help

Comment: this should not be getting close votes. it is a perfectly clear question. we know that there is a bijection from $\mathbb{Q}^n$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. OP wants to know if there exists a bijection that is a polynomial function in the domain.

Comment: yes of course this what i want , i asked it before to seek if there is inverse application of p but it was unclear

Comment: Relevant - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q

Comment: This is probably an open problem.